# What does the o mean in this method - bool IsSatisfiedBy(T o) C#

Tags: c#

I was in the middle of reading a C# tutorial and came across this method below:-

```
public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T o);
```

What is the o? Is it another parameter? If so, it doesnt make sense that you would define another parameter that way.

The tutorial then defines this method :-

```
public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T o)   {
    return this.expression(o);
}
```

If you require any more info to answer the question just let me know, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yep I see it now, I was being silly - its the same as doing (string hello)

Comment: Yeah I just realised, just came to me then, I was being silly. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like "o" is just a generic parameter of type T.

You can take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx for more details.

Comment: I agree that it looks like that but (to be picky) without showing the enclosing class definition like class C<T>, T could very well be a regular type. Using T for a generic type is just a convention. Especially in tutorials, a type T could be a regular type, just as C can be a class.

Comment: You are correct. I shouldn't have made that assumption or at least I should have stated all the assumptions as part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`o` is a Parameter, of the generic Type `T`, which is defined in the class definition.

Comment: Not necessarily, see my remark at Stefan Ch's answer.